# mouse leave fails on multiple ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

When i perform mouseenter event on an anchor tag the tooltip is displayed and on mouseleave tooltip hides.This works fine.

But when i quickly move my mouse from multiple anchor tags(cause multiple ajax request) then the last tooltip does not hides even when the mouse is not on the anchor tag.(Basically the tooltip of anchor tag on which the mouse entered the last before completing the ajax request)

Description of what i have done:

I have to show a tooltip on my anchor tag on mouseenter event.

So, in order to show the details in tooltip related to anchor tag(anchor tag is list of ids of a table) i have added an id(tooltipWindow) inside div

```
<div id='tooltipWindow'> </div>
```

so, on mouseenter on an anchor tag, i send an ajax request give as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(td a).live('mouseenter', function(e){
  $.ajax({
    url: controller/action,
    data: $(this).text(),
    dataType: script,
    success: function(){
      calculate xposition ad ypostion and set the postion of tooltip
    }
  });
});
```

});

And in js.erb file(ruby on rails)

```
$(#tooltipWindow).show();
$(this).html(<%= partial template which is shown in tooltip by passing locals %>);
```

on mouseleave event i just the hide the tooltip and empty the div.

```
$(td a).live('mouseleave', function(){
  $(#tooltipWindow).hide();
  $(#tooltipWindow).empty();
});
```

i tried to replace mouseleave with mouseout but it did'nt work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just an FYI, `.live()` has been deprecated. You should us `.on()` instead.

Comment: Actually i am using jquery 1.8.3 in my project, so  i am using live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the wrong syntax to get the text of anchor

```
data: $(this).val(),   // It does not have a value property
```

Replace it with

```
data: $(this).text(),
```

To avoid multiple Ajax requests when you move your mouse too fast, it is better to use `setTimeout` to handle the situation and clearing it frequently and avoiding multiple requests.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    $('td a').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'controller/action',
                data: $(this).text(),
                dataType: script,
                success: function () {
                    calculate xposition ad ypostion and set the postion of tooltip
                }
            });
        }, 300);
    });

    $('td a').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $('#tooltipWindow').hide();
        $('#tooltipWindow').empty();
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
});
```

Comment: No i have only one id on my view page. i just calculate the position of my anchor tag and then display the tooltip on mouseenter event.

Comment: in my code i have written $(this).text(), i guess i mistakenly wrote $(this).val() in box. i will correct it. FYI, i pass this id inside my controller, in params i get this id value, i fetch record by writing a query and pass the records details o be displayed on my tooltip.